# Intermediate Topics in Synchronous Kafka: Using Spring Request-Reply

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

With the latest release of spring-kakfa, we are trying to use request-reply semantics and would like to know if we can use intermediate topics with out losing correlation id. One of our usecase is to receive a message from an api produce it to topic1 and and the result to topic2 and process the message on topic2 and send it to topic3 where topic3 sends the final response to the initial request from topic1.

I am not able to associate the response coming from topic3 to the request on topic1 as the correlationid gets lost in the intermediate topic. I am able to receive the message if I don't use intermediate topic (say topic2) then topic1 sends a message with a correlationid and its corresponding response is received from topic3.

Any suggestions /recommendations are greatly helpful.

Below is sample code: 
From my API I am posting a transaction

```
public String postTransaction(String request,Map<String, String> headers) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ProducerRecord<String,String> record=new ProducerRecord<String,String>(topic1,"300",request);
    record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC,topic3.getBytes()));
    RequestReplyFuture<String,String,String> sendAndReceive=kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
    SendResult<String,String> requestMessage=sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();
    return sendAndReceive.get().value();
}
```

#

In Another consumer, I am listening on topic1 and taking the correlation id and producing message on topic2 which will send a reply to topic3.

```
public void listen(Object request, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) List<Integer> keys,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) List<String> topics,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] coRlId) throws InterruptedException {

    ProducerRecord<String,String> record=new ProducerRecord<String,String>("topic2","300",k.value());
    record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID,coRlId.get(0).getBytes()));

    kafkaTemplate.send(record);

}
```

Comment: Your intermediate application that reads from topic 2 and writes to topic3 needs to propagate the `KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` header from the input record to the output record.

Comment: I tried to propagate KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID from topic2 to topic3 to from the initial request but somehow the id is not matching with the KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID I set in the initial request. and I am getting time out error. Apologies if this is dumb question, I am new to this area, but am I missing something here ? How the KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID gets changed

Comment: Unfortunately, they closed this question so I can't add an example in an answer. You must be doing something wrong; if you propagate the correlation id header properly, the caller application will be able to correlate the reply, regardless of how many steps it took.

Comment: I just added sample code , Can you please take a look or add an example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and it works just fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61152047Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61152047Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyer(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {

        containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = replyContainer(containerFactory);
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = containerFactory.createContainer("topic3");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("three");
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rkt) {
        return args -> {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic1", "foo", "bar");
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future = rkt.sendAndReceive(pr);
            System.out.println(future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic3").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "one", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen1(String in,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] corrId) {

        System.out.println(in);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic2", in.toUpperCase());
        pr.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, corrId));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(pr);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "two", topics = "topic2")
    @SendTo("topic3")
    public String listen2(String in) {
        return in + in;
    }

}
```

and

```
bar
BARBAR
```

You can also propagate the reply-to header(s)...

```java
    @KafkaListener(id = "one", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen1(String in,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] corrId) {

        System.out.println(in);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic2", in.toUpperCase());
        pr.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, replyTo));
        pr.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, corrId));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(pr);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "two", topics = "topic2")
    @SendTo // ("topic3")
    public String listen2(String in) {
        return in + in;
    }
```

**EDIT**

To convey the correlation id via the payload:

```java
public class CorrelatingProducerInterceptor implements ProducerInterceptor<String, Foo> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<String, Foo> onSend(ProducerRecord<String, Foo> record) {
        Header correlation = record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID);
        if (correlation != null) {
            record.value().setCorrelation(correlation.value());
        }
        return record;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAcknowledgement(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61152047Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61152047Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Foo> kafkaTemplate;

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Foo, Foo> replyer(ProducerFactory<String, Foo> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Foo> containerFactory) {

        containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Foo> container = replyContainer(containerFactory);
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Foo, Foo> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Foo> replyContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Foo> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Foo> container = containerFactory.createContainer("topic3");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("three");
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Foo> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Foo> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Foo, Foo> rkt) {
        return args -> {
            ProducerRecord<String, Foo> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic1", "foo", new Foo("bar"));
            RequestReplyFuture<String, Foo, Foo> future = rkt.sendAndReceive(pr);
            System.out.println(future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic3").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "one", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen1(Foo in) {

        System.out.println(in);
        in.setContent(in.getContent().toUpperCase());
        ProducerRecord<String, Foo> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic2", in);
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(pr);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "two", topics = "topic2")
    public void listen2(Foo in) {
        ProducerRecord<String, Foo> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("topic3", new Foo(in.getContent() + in.getContent()));
        pr.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, in.getCorrelation()));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(pr);
    }

}

class Foo {

    String content;

    byte[] correlation;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public byte[] getCorrelation() {
        return this.correlation;
    }

    public void setCorrelation(byte[] correlation) {
        this.correlation = correlation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [content=" + this.content + "]";
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.example.demo.Foo

spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.interceptor.classes=com.example.demo.CorrelatingProducerInterceptor
```

and

```
Foo [content=bar]
Foo [content=BARBAR]
```

Of course, the intermediate app needs to pass the correlation id, even when it's in the payload.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, Its working with above code  . But if the intermediate topics are some third party kafka stream applications where we don't have control to set the headers , in that case I tried to hold the correlation id and consume the message from the third party application and producer it to the reply topic by setting the correlation id . But unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: If app2 doesn't propagate the header, where are you getting the correlation id from in app3?

Comment: just for the testing purpose , I tried passing the correlationid in the payload and took it in app3 and added it to the header before sending to the reply topic.

Comment: I modified my test to convey the correlation data in the payload; of course, your intermediate app needs to pass it along. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Gary . Since my downstream applications are taking payload in string format,  I tried to set the value in  record.value().concat("correlationid in string format") but I don't see the value gets updated in the record.. Also i tried to append some sample string to record.value().concant(), that didn't work. however if we use POJO, like in your example I can see the value updated.

Comment: `ProducerRecords` are immutable and, in any case, so are Strings `record.value().concat(...)` just creates a new String which, presumably, you just discard; you need to create a new `ProducerRecord` from the old one, with the new value.

Comment: @GaryRussell will this work when I have multiple partitions in the reply topic and the message is written to the reply topic by an app outside spring ?

Comment: Yes, but if you have multiple instances of the client side, you will need to propagate the reply topic and reply partition headers as well as the correlation id. If you have further questions; don't ask them here; start a new question.